# Return value diff between Postgres and MySql for booleans

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

If I do this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select 1 as t').first
```

on Postgres and MySql I get this:

```
MySql: [1]
Postgres: {"t"=>"1"}
```

Can someone explain what that is about?!

Comment: Presumably a bug in the MySQL driver. Report it to the developers...

Comment: I'd rather say that it is a bug in the postgres driver. 1 is an int and gets returned as a string...

Comment: Bug in both, then. The integer should be returned with its name in the case of MySQL...

Comment: Yeah - we do agree that the postgres driver should return the value as an int, right? I don't understand why this is not more of a problem - googling it returns very little on the subject and in my current project I have to do .to_i a lot of strange places.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of where the bug is, this shows an interesting difference between the two databases (and an example of why cross-db abstraction is hard).

MySQL has no true bool type as such.  It merely uses tinyints as boolean values.

**On MySQL:**

```
SELECT true;
+------+
| TRUE |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Boolean expressions also evaluate to integers:

```
select true is not false;
+-------------------+
| true is not false |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**On PostgreSQL**

PostgreSQL supports a true boolean type with either a 't' or an 'f' returned.

```
select true;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)

select true is not false;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Note you can also cast ints to bool:

```
select 1::bool;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)

select 2::bool;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)

select 0::bool;
 bool 
------
 f
(1 row)
```

Evidently the two authors of these packages had different ideas of how to address the question of boolean types.